# Angular Update Package CSS-WHAT

Tags: angular, npm

I have the following angular setup:

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 12.0.3
Node: 14.17.0
Package Manager: npm 7.16.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 12.0.4
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... localize, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1200.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1102.14
@angular-devkit/core            12.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.0.3
@angular/cli                    12.0.3
@schematics/angular             12.0.3
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.2.4
```

I am having issue when running, npm audit --audit-level high. It is returning a few issue and one of them is the following:

```
css-what  <5.0.1
Severity: high
Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1754
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.901.15, which is a breaking change
node_modules/css-what
  css-select  <=3.1.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of css-what
  node_modules/css-select
    svgo  >=1.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      postcss-svgo  >=4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/postcss-svgo
        cssnano-preset-default  *
        Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-svgo
        node_modules/cssnano-preset-default
          cssnano  >=4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9
          Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano-preset-default
          node_modules/cssnano
            @angular-devkit/build-angular  *
            Depends on vulnerable versions of @angular-devkit/build-webpack
            Depends on vulnerable versions of resolve-url-loader
            Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
            Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
            node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
```

I run the following update to attempt resolve the issue,

```
npm update css-what
```

but i still get the same issue.

Can anyone help me here? How do i resolve the audit warning?

Comment: I am facing the same problem but haven't found a solution yet. But it looks like css-what is a dependencie of another package, so you can't update it directly. i think this is a problem inside a library.

Answer (score 1):

I am having identical issue and I couldn't find a solution to this vulnerability.

I've found out that you simply CAN NOT directly manually update css-what

```
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest
// or
npm install css-what@latest
```

because css-select is indirect dependancy.

> The latest possible version that can be installed is 4.0.0 because of
> the following conflicting dependency:
>
> @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.0.3 requires css-what@^4.0.0 via a
> transitive dependency on css-select@3.1.2 The earliest fixed version
> is 5.0.1.

This dependancy HASN'T been fixed in `@angular-devkit/build-angular@12.0.5` either.

There are also threads about it:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/21185